# Python list automatization

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

The following problem may be a bit confusing but I will try to explain it in the best possible way.

Let's assume that we work for a manufacturing company. Which manufactures components that are then used to make products. In the following example there are 3 components and 2 final products.

The **demands** of components and products are the following:

```
comp1 = 7
comp2 = 3
comp3 = 4
prod1 = 2
prod2 = 1
prod3 = 0
```

Which can be saved in a dictionary:

```
clst = {"comp": [comp1, comp2, comp3], "prod": [prod1, prod2, prod3]}
```

On the other hand, to manufacture a final product, the components requirements are the following:

prod1 need: 2 comp1, 1 comp2, 1 comp3

prod2 need: 3 comp1, 1 comp2, 2 comp3

prod3 need: 2 comp1, 2 comp2, 2 comp3

In a dictionary:

```
rprod = {0: [2,1,1], 1: [3,1,2], 2: [2,2,2]}
```

I need to get this Expected Output:

```
  lst=  [
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -2, -3],  
            [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1],    
            [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -2]   
        ]
```

**Logic behind the output:**

1. The main list have 3 sublist because there are 3 components. The idea is that each sublist represents inputs and consumptions for a type of component
2. **Input**: The first elements of a sublist correspond to the units of components produced. The number of times corresponding to the demand of the component must be written down "1". 
   **Example**: Let see the list for comp1 (first sublist), we know the demand of Comp1 is 7 so the sublist should start as follows:

   Input = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
3. **Consumption**: Now we need to incorporate the product demands to the sublist, but these instead of contributing (+), consume (-). The demands of products are:

   prod1 = 2 
   prod2 = 1 
   prod3 = 0

we also know that a product consume:

```
rprod = {0: [2,1,1], 1: [3,1,2], 2: [2,2,2]}
key 0 = prod 1 
key 1 = prod 2 
key 2 = prod 3
```

**Example**: Consumption list of comp1 for the products will be:

```
  Consumption =  [-2, -2, -3]
```

that is equal to `[rprod[0][0], rprod[1][0], rprod[2][0]]`

So finally the sublist for comp1 will be Input + Consuption:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -2, -3]
```

Any suggestions to make the list?

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the expected output

Comment: maybe you could understand it after reading this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173693/discussion-between-poppinyoshi-and-jpss

Comment: Now I can not answer the chat because I have 19 points and not 20

Comment: Now you can answer the chat

Comment: There's a delay, so I still can not talk on the chat

Comment: Oh really so then i think we should talk in comments

Comment: Ok. So, i think you understand that the list I want to create contains a number of sublists equal to the number of components that exist. The next thing to understand is that each sublist is associated with the manufacture of components and the use of these. This is why each sublist is built with two things: 1: inputs, 2: consumptions.
**Inputs** is to add the amount of 1 equivalent to the demand for components. **consumptions** is to add the consumed quantity of components for each product

Comment: Please be sure to try to produce the code rather than just presenting the issue.

Comment: your consumption part of question is still unclear .

Answer (score 0):

i think it's ok. that's a bit messy but you'll hopefully get the idea

```
rprod = {0: [2,1,1], 1: [3,1,2], 2: [2,2,2]}

comp = [7, 3, 4]
flat_comp = [[1]*x for x in comp]  # [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]

# turn prod into a list of rprod indices
prod = [2, 1, 0]
flat_prod = [i for i, x in enumerate(prod) for _ in range(x)]  # [0, 0, 1]

result = [[] for _ in range(len(comp))]
for i in range(len(comp)):
    result[i] = flat_comp[i]
    for production in flat_prod:
        result[i].append(-rprod[production][i])

print(result)  # [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -2, -3], [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -2]]
```